# Is it possible to get another field of row I'm trying to duplicate in PSQL or MyBatis?

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, psql

I have a table 'client', which has 3 columns - id, siebel_id, phone_number.
PhoneNumber has a unique constraint. If I save a new client with an existing number, I'll get an error `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "phone_number_unique"`.
Is it possible to make PSQL or MyBatis showing 'siebel_id' of a record where the phone number already saved?
I mean to get a message like

```
'ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "phone_number_unique"
  Detail: Key (phone_number)=(+79991234567) already exists on siebel_id...'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to tweak the internal message that the PostgreSQL database engine returns accompannying an error. Well... unless you recompiled the whole PostgreSQL database from scratch, and I would assume this is off the table.

However, you can easily search for the offending row using SQL, as in:

```
select siebel_id from client where phone_number = '+79991234567';
```